# I have a problem in configuring virtual box to genymotion

Tags: virtualbox, genymotion

I have installed genymotion so as usual it's two icons created on my desktop one generation and other it's shell.
Now I want to configure/run in virtual box.
I have started virtual box click on new and set the requirements as linux and version=linux 2.x/3.x/4.x (64).
And configured the storage. But when I started it by click on start it ask me to choose a file for it but it not showing me the genymotion file instead it is just showing me genemotion folder.

My problem is how to add genymotion like how I added other os

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to run Genymotion in a virtual machine? If so, it will not work: Genymotion needs direct access to your host machine hardware.
See https://support.genymotion.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002720057-Can-Genymotion-Desktop-run-in-a-virtual-machine-

Comment: Thnaks you ......